# SSH local port forwarding to locally unknown port number

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I want to forward a local port via a jump server where the destination port can change and is only known to the jump server, but not to localhost.

## The setup

`localhost` has only access to the jump server via SSH.

`destination`: has a port I want to access via local port forwarding from localhost. The port number can change in unknown intervals. I can not SSH into the destination, I can only forward ports to it.

`jump_server`:
The jump server runs a script which regularly gets the valid port number I need to forward to.

## My current guess to solve this

1. let the script on `jump_server` write the port number into an env variable
2. create local port forward from `localhost` to the `jump_server` (with fixed ports)
3. create a local only port forward on `jump_server` which forwards the incoming fixed port from step2 to the port from the env variable
4. chain the commands so it does not require interaction

## My questions

1. The idea seems inefficient and the local only port forward from step 3 seems wrong. Is there a better way to solve this?
2. If there is no better way: How should the command chain look like for step4?

Comment: It would be much effecient to set up a vpn.

Comment: Supposing you already know the final server's destination port, would the command `ssh -J jump_server final_server -L localport:final_server:final_port -Nf` work?